# RTMP stream works in Windows VLC but not in Linux (Ubuntu) VLC or any other application in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, vlc

I have a HTTP server which gives me access to a RTMP stream. 
    I am facing a very strange issue that this RTMP stream works perfectly fine in **Windows's VLC player** but **not in the Ubuntu's VLC player**. VLC gives the error:

```
*core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for rtmp://gm-tky-vs04.myspotcam.com/live/SWA010beuh7u
avio error**: Failed to open rtmp://gm-tky-vs04.myspotcam.com/live/SWA010beuh7u: Unknown error 1313558101
core debug: no access modules matched**
core error: open of `rtmp://gm-tky-vs04.myspotcam.com/live/SWA010beuh7u' failed
core debug: dead input
core debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
core debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input*
```

When I tried taking the rtmpdump  via flvstreamer of this RTMP stream in My ubuntu system and here is the error I am getting:

```
DEBUG: RTMPSockBuf_Fill, recv returned -1. GetSockError(): 104 (Connection reset by peer)
ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
DEBUG: Closing connection.
```

**System Confugiration: Ubuntu 16.04 64 byte
    Anyone with any idea? The complete logs are**:

```
*/GST/FRSampleApp/Release# flvstreamer -r"rtmp://gm-tky-vs04.myspotcam.com/live/SWA010beuh7u" --debug --verbos
FLVStreamer v2.1c1
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
WARNING: You haven't specified an output file (-o filename), using stdout
DEBUG: Protocol : RTMP
DEBUG: Hostname : gm-tky-vs04.myspotcam.com
DEBUG: Port     : 1935
DEBUG: Playpath : SWA010beuh7u
DEBUG: tcUrl    : rtmp://gm-tky-vs04.myspotcam.com:1935/live
DEBUG: swfUrl   : (null)
DEBUG: pageUrl  : (null)
DEBUG: app      : live
DEBUG: auth     : (null)
DEBUG: subscribepath : (null)
DEBUG: flashVer : LNX 10,0,22,87
DEBUG: live     : no
DEBUG: timeout  : 120 sec
DEBUG: Setting buffer time to: 36000000ms
Connecting ...
DEBUG: RTMP_Connect1, ... connected, handshaking
DEBUG: HandShake: Type Answer   : 03
DEBUG: HandShake: Server Uptime : 387900349
DEBUG: HandShake: FMS Version   : -19.103.19.-49
DEBUG: RTMP_Connect1, handshaked
DEBUG: Invoking connect
INFO: Connected...
DEBUG: HandleServerBW: server BW = 2500000
DEBUG: HandleClientBW: client BW = 2500000 2
DEBUG: HandleCtrl, received ctrl. type: 0, len: 6
DEBUG: HandleCtrl, Stream Begin 0
DEBUG: RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 189 bytes
DEBUG: (object begin)
DEBUG: (object begin)
DEBUG: Property: <Name:                    fmsVer, STRING:  FMS/3,0,1,123>
DEBUG: Property: <Name:              capabilities, NUMBER:  31.00>
DEBUG: (object end)
DEBUG: (object begin)
DEBUG: Property: <Name:                     level, STRING:  status>
DEBUG: Property: <Name:                      code, STRING:  NetConnection.Connect.Success>
DEBUG: Property: <Name:               description, STRING:  Connection succeeded>
DEBUG: Property: <Name:            objectEncoding, NUMBER:  0.00>
DEBUG: (object end)
DEBUG: (object end)
DEBUG: HandleInvoke, server invoking <_result>
DEBUG: HandleInvoke, received result for method call <connect>
DEBUG: sending ctrl. type: 0x0003
DEBUG: Invoking createStream
DEBUG: RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 30 bytes
DEBUG: (object begin)
DEBUG: Property: NULL
DEBUG: (object end)
DEBUG: HandleInvoke, server invoking <onBWDone>
DEBUG: Invoking _checkbw
DEBUG: RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 29 bytes
DEBUG: (object begin)
DEBUG: Property: NULL
DEBUG: (object end)
DEBUG: HandleInvoke, server invoking <_result>
DEBUG: HandleInvoke, received result for method call <createStream>
DEBUG: SendPlay, seekTime=0.00, dLength=0, sending play: SWA010beuh7u
DEBUG: Invoking play
DEBUG: sending ctrl. type: 0x0003
DEBUG: RTMPSockBuf_Fill, recv returned -1. GetSockError(): 104 (Connection reset by peer)
ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
DEBUG: Closing connection.*
```